# Why are some special characters missing after copying package from sql developer?

Tags: sql, oracle

I just recently faced a problem, after updating an existing oracle package I copied it from sql developer and pasted in notepad editor, saved the file and shared it with deployment team  to update on production environment.

When production team executed the package there were many errors in it.

After investigation it was found that special characters '**:**', '**|**' and '**>**' were  missing from the file.

Now I have to share the root cause why the special characters were missing, i tried to produce the same scenario again by copying from sql developer and pasting it in notepad but the issue did not occur again.

Does anyone know why this issue occurs?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be aware of extended ASCII and possible UTF8 characters used in your scripts.  You need to use an editor aware of character sets such as Ultraedit, or save the file from plsql developer to share it for deployment.  That being said, notepad should be fine with extended ASCII but not UTF8.  Characters like ":" are normal ASCII so should never have been rejected.  Sometimes, SQL editors like plsql developer or sql navigator have built-in copy and paste code, and there might have been a buggy copy the first time you tried.